# How to unpack a list?

Tags: python, list

Given a function `func(*args)` and a list, how can I 'unpack' the list such that I pass its contents as separate arguments?

I know I can do `func(*thelist)`, but what I actually want to do is pass along another object, besides the contents of the list; something like this `func(someobj, *thelist)`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Well, you have unpacked it; but the function definition repacks it. Remove the `*` from `func(*args) and you'll get individual arguments. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Tom The function is from a third-party library, I can't modify it.

Comment: `func(someobj, *thelist)` should work. How is that unsatisfactory?

Comment: @Tom I didn't try it out and didn't expect it to work, so I asked. :| I should have tried it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will work exactly as you typed it.

```
def foo(*mylist):
    bar("first", *mylist)

def bar(*vals):
    print "|".join(vals)

foo("a","b")
```

will print:

```
first|a|b
```

Comment: If the answer is, "you already have it," then that is the answer.

Comment: My comment was in response to a comment, now gone, that said, "Shouldn't that be a comment?"   This is getting very meta...

Comment: Well, the original answer was so short, it should have been a comment. I removed it after you expanded the answer.